# Android Exception: Failed to find configuration root that contains xxx

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I get an Exception problem from the getUriForFile method, I'm trying to capture an image when I click on a Button but the application is crashing when I do it.

My logs are:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/XXXX/cache/JPEG_20161125_153048_-942097512.jpg
                  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
                  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
                  at com.example.pierre.mycamera.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On my manifest file, I have written this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="XXXX"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

file_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/XXXX/files/Pictures/" />
</paths>
```

My onClick method:

```
if(v.getId == ...){

Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
photoFile = createImageFile();
photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.pierre.mycamera", photoFile);
captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
startActivityForResult(captureIntent,1);
}
```

The createImageFile:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
    );
    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your stack trace does not match your code. Your code has `getExternalFilesDir()`. But `/data/data/XXXX/cache` should be `getCacheDir()`

Comment: What do you mean? Should I add a specific method?

Comment: "What do you mean?" -- I mean that the output that you show (the stack trace at the top of your question) seems to be generated by different code than you have in your question.

Comment: That's weird, because I can ensure you it's from this code.

Comment: To fix it, should I add mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getCatchDir().getAbsolutePath(); ? Or this isn't you mean?

Comment: I can't tell you how to fix it, because I cannot explain what you are seeing. `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` should be located on external storage (whose location varies, but is not `/data/data/`, which is internal storage). And, it should have `Pictures`, or something resembling that, in the path. Neither fits `/data/data/XXXX/cache/JPEG_20161125_153048_-942097512.jpg`. All that I can suggest is that you add logging, breakpoints, or something to determine where things are going awry between where you think the path is and what `getUriForFile()` is receiving as a `File`.

Comment: If I am correct, and you have some `getCacheDir()` code in there that is really generating the `File` for `getUriForFile()`, you need to decide which of those two locations (`getCacheDir()` or `getExternalFilesDir()`) you really want to use for the photo. Either is fine, though `FileProvider` scares me somewhat with `getExternalFilesDir()` (which is why I am looking to add `getExternalFilesDir()` support to my `StreamProvider` soon).  But your `File` and your `file_paths.xml` need to be in sync, and at present, they do not appear to be.

Comment: When, I check my code, there is no getCacheDir() method. I try to put android:installLocation="preferExternal" on Manifest, but didn't work either.